# Is it possible to prevent or stop the teargas?

Tags: payday-2

In the bank heist (and perhaps other heists), the cops can send teargas through the vents.

[image: teargas in the bank heist]

I think it's possible to prevent it by killing the cops on the roof, but is it possible to stop it afterward ?  The gas tank is pretty easy to spot, but can't be destroyed or interacted with.

[image: teargas gas tank]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only way to prevent the gas is by killing the cops on the roof, which get dropped via a chopper.
Bane warns you when a chopper is inbound, so get up there and liquidate them.

If there is already tear-gas, you cannot "switch it of". I searched for quite a bit, but cannot find something that states that you can get rid of tear-gas.

Comment: Yep, I tried shooting the gas canister and everything but to no avail.